# How to hide navigation bar when image is tapped

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar

How would I hide the navigation bar once my imageView is tapped, the navigation bar messes up the view of the full screen image once my imageView is tapped and I would like it hidden when the image is tapped and to reappear once the image is dismissed. Here is my code for my image being tapped.

```
//expandImage




@IBAction func expand(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
    newImageView.frame = self.view.frame
    newImageView.backgroundColor = .black
    newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreen))
    newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
}

func dismissFullscreen(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your expand() method:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

And in dismissFullscreen() method:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

Or you can create new ViewController, pass image to it (with segue e.g) and add this to viewDidLoad() of new ViewController:

```
self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
```

Answer (score 2):

So here is how you can do that:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tapImageScrollView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(_:)))
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapImageScrollView)
    }

    func imageTapped(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden == false {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        } else {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

So basically add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `imageView` and in the `imageTapped` function you check if the `navigationBar` is not hidden then you want to show the image and hide the `navigationBar` and if you click on the `imageView` again you want to show the `navigationBar` again.

So simply add the logic in imageTapped to your `dismissFullscreen` function.